# move_uploaded_file in PHP not working?

Tags: php, html, mysql, file-upload

I'm actively learning [php](/questions/tagged/php) and am working on a CMS Project. I'm stuck on image upload.

**PHP**

```
 if ( $_POST['img'])
 $uploads_dir = '/images';
 $tmp_name = $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"];
 $name = $_FILES["img"]["name"];
 move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
```

**HTML**

```
 <img src="images/$image" />
```

**MySQL**

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO affordplan VALUES('$title','$name','$bodytext','$created')";
  return mysql_query($sql);
```

The name of the file is uploaded to database but the file itself is not being uploaded to the destination folder.

Comment: First: use absolute path in `$uploads_dir`. Second - change `$_POST['img']` to `$_FILES['img']`

Comment: once you have folder `images` and once `/images` - decide. These are two different paths

Comment: also use proper php code for variable

Comment: It is also a good idea to check the `$_FILES["img"]['error']` for any non zero status

Comment: share you html which submits file  ?

Answer (score 0):

*Type your html code in between form and in the form wrtie as following*

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<img src="images/$image" name="img" />
...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_FILES` to check file is posted or not instead of `$_POST`. Also make proper quote for variables. Then for echo php variable use php tags.
 Try

**PHP:**

```
if ( $_FILES['img'])
 $uploads_dir = 'images'; // will be on same location where php file exist.
 $tmp_name = $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"];
 $name = $_FILES["img"]["name"];
 move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $uploads_dir.'/'.$name);
```

**HTML:**

```
 <img src="images/<?php echo $image;?>" />
```

**MySQL:**

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO affordplan VALUES('$title','$name','$bodytext','$created')";
  return mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

// Upload multiple files to the folder

```
   $upload_dir = '/images';
   if ( $_FILES['img']){
    foreach ($_FILES["img"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
        if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            $tmp_name = $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"][$key];
            $name = $_FILES["img"]["name"][$key];
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$upload_dir/$name");
        }
    }
   }
```

//MySQL
MySQL:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO affordplan VALUES('$title','$name','$bodytext','$created')";
  return mysql_query($sql);
```

HTML used in form submission

```
<input type="file" name="img" multiple>
```

Showing the images in HTML

```
$dir = "/images/";
$images = glob($dir."*.jpg");
foreach($images as $image) {
echo '<img src="'.$image.'" /><br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a directory that is equivalent to the file name. Try this

```html
<?php 
  if (!file_exist("your main directory/the file to story")) {
    mkdir("your main directory/the file to story", 0777, true);
  }

  // then you start uploading your once the folder is created
?>
```

The process here is if the folder directory doesn't exist, the `mkdir()` function will create that folder. Then that's the time you start on moving the file to the created folder.

Answer (score 0):

Put all of your code in if statement:

```
if ( $_POST['img']) {
    $uploads_dir = '/images';
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"];
    $name = $_FILES["img"]["name"];
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form action="phpfilename.php" method="post" 
       enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input  type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">

 

$file=$_FILES['file']['name'];
$dest="uploads/$file";
$src=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
move_uploaded_file($src,$dest);

$result=mysql_query("insert into tablename(dbfieldname) values('$dest')");
```